# Filter in DJANGO using Multiple Select Form

Tags: python, html, django, forms, filter

I have a single form input (see below) where a user can filter Workshop objects based on multiple properties like name, what equipment it has, if it has equipment with certain capabilities and material functionality, etc.

Form:
[image]

Form Template:

```
    <form method="get" action=".">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>WHAT ARE YOU LOOKING FOR?</legend>
            <div class="suggestion-wrap">
            <span>Workshop</span>
            <span>Equipment</span>
            <span>Materials</span>
            <span>Capabilities</span>
          </div>
            <div class="inner-form">
            <div class="input-field">
              <select multiple placeholder="Type to search..." name="name_contains" id="choices-text-preset-values" class="form-control">

                  {% for Material in material_list %}
                  <option>{{ Material.material }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}

                  {% for MachineType in machinetype_list %}
                    <option>{{ MachineType.machineType }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}

                  {% for Capabilities in capabilities_list %}
                  <option>{{ Capabilities.capabilities }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}

                  {% for Workshop in workshop_list %}
                  <option>{{ Workshop.workshop_name }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}

                  {% for Equipment in equipment_list %}
                  <option>{{ Equipment.equipment_name }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}


              </select>
                <div class="select-dropdown"></div>

                <button class="btn-search" type="submit">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
                </svg>
              </button>

            </div>
          </div>


        </fieldset>

        <!-- <button class="btn-submit" type="submit">search</button> -->


      </form>
```

As you can see this is a select multiple field with options from each of the searchable categories. It is designed to be an all in one seach bar. For this example (see image above) Id like to be able to show all workshops which have equipment that can Mill steel and aluminum.

When you press search the URL looks like:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?name_contains=Mill&name_contains=Steel&name_contains=Aluminium

This is what I have tried so far:
Views.py:

```
def BootstrapFilterView(request):
    qs = Workshop.objects.all()

    name_contains_query = request.GET.get('name_contains')

    if is_valid_queryparam(name_contains_query):
        qs = Workshop.objects.filter(Q(workshop_name__icontains=name_contains_query)
                                 | Q(equipment__equipment_name__icontains=name_contains_query)
                                 , Q(equipment__equipment_materials__material__icontains=name_contains_query)
                                 , Q(equipment__equipment_capabilities__capabilities__icontains=name_contains_query)
                                 , Q(equipment__equipment_machineType__machineType__icontains=name_contains_query)
                                 ).distinct()


capabilities_list = Capabilities.objects.order_by('capabilities')
    machinetype_list = MachineType.objects.order_by('machineType')
    material_list = Material.objects.order_by('material')

    equipment_list = Equipment.objects.all()
    workshop_list = Workshop.objects.all()

    print(name_contains_query)
    return render(request, "bootstrap_form.html", {'capabilities_list': capabilities_list,
                                                   'material_list': material_list,
                                                   'machinetype_list': machinetype_list,
                                                   'equipment_list': equipment_list,
                                                   'workshop_list': workshop_list,
                                                   'queryset': qs
                                                   })
```

The goal of this filter is to display:

1. The workshop if a tag with the name of the workshop was added
2. all workshops with a certain piece of equipment which has specific properties

Currently, I don't know how to pass in the entire list of search tags that were entered.
using this URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?name_contains=Mill&name_contains=Steel&name_contains=Aluminium

the filters only use the last tag, in this case Aluminium. How can i get it to use all of them:
Mill, Steel, Aluminium

I think i can get it to work if I can just make a new array or list out of all the entered tags. Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From django QueryDict  `getlist()` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)

> QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)
>
> Returns a list of the data with the requested key. Returns an empty
> list if the key doesn’t exist and a default value wasn’t provided.
> It’s guaranteed to return a list unless the default value provided
> isn’t a list.

```
request.GET.getlist('name_contains')
```

Comment: and how can I filter using this?

Comment: this seems to work:  qs = Workshop.objects.filter(Q(workshop_name__in=search_items) | Q(equipment__equipment_name__in=search_items)).distinct()